# MPC controller with gekko example question

Tags: python, controller, gekko

I'm trying to model an example use case of temperature control. I have the code below.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

class Model(GEKKO):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    nt = 60
    self.time = np.linspace(0,10,nt)

    R = self.Const(value=2) # Thermal resistance 
    C = self.Const(value=0.5) # Thermal capacity

    self.T0 = self.FV(value=12) # External temperature
    self.T0.FSTATUS = 1

    # Variables
    self.T = self.CV(value=22)
    self.T.STATUS = 1 
    self.options.CV_TYPE = 2
    self.T.SP = 24
    self.T.TR_INIT = 1

    self.q1 = self.MV(value=0) # Heating power
    self.q1.DCOST = 1
    self.q1.STATUS = 1

    self.q3 = self.FV(value=0.5) # Another internal heat source
    self.q3.FSTATUS = 1

    # Equations
    self.Equation(R * C * self.T.dt() + self.T == R * self.q1 + self.T0 + R * self.q3)

    self.options.IMODE = 6 # optimal control mode

  def optimize(self):
    self.solve(disp=False) # solve
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    T0 = np.random.normal(13, 0.1, 60) # External temeprature varies randomly over time
    q3 = np.random.normal(2, 0.01, 60) # Internal heat generation varies randomly over time
    q1 = np.zeros(30)
    temp = np.zeros(30)
    
    m = Model()

    for t in range(30):
      m.T0.MEAS = T0[t]
      m.q3.MEAS = q3[t]

      m.optimize()
      if (m.options.APPSTATUS==1):
        q1[t] = m.q1.NEWVAL
        temp[t] = m.T.PRED[1]
      else:
        q1[t] = 0    
        temp[t] = 0    

      m.q1.MEAS = q1[t]
      m.T.MEAS = temp[t]
      
      plt.plot(np.arange(30),q1,'b-',label=r'$q1$')
      plt.show()
      
      plt.plot(np.arange(30),temp,'b-',label=r'$q1$')
      plt.show()
```

I have the following questions that you might be able to help me with.

- The model has two time scales: the total time horizon (30 minutes) and the prediction horizon (1 minute) of the controller. If the prediction horizon is not long enough for the controller to reach the set point and then the environment updates, the behavior of the controller may not be able to behave smoothly. I think this is what we see in the plots in the notebook I send to you. Of course, it depends on how random the environment is. Do you have any suggestions to achieve a balance between the two time scales to improve controller behavior (other than trial and error)?
- Could you please confirm that I have modeled the main "for" loop correctly? For example, the way I read the first prediction from the controller and updates the system in the next time step is correct or not. For example, I'm not sure whether TR_INIT option automatically takes care of the update that I do inside the loop for the CV.

Thank you.

I modeled the problem using Gekko (code given above), the result can also be seen in the plots via the code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The application looks correct with a few minor modifications:

- There is no need to update the model with measured `q1` and `T` values unless these come from a measurement. The current implement records the model prediction and then inserts that same model prediction. Gekko stores the current model value and performs the correct time-shift so that the next time point becomes the new initial condition when `m.solve()` is called.

```py
    # Remove
    # m.q1.MEAS = q1[t]
    # m.T.MEAS = temp[t]
```

- The time scale issue can be helped by using an irregular time sequence. The first time step needs to be the cycle time of the controller. The time sequence can increase in step size to the point that steady-state is reached. Deciding on the time steps is an important tuning configuration for the controller. More time steps give a more accurate solution, but the computational time increases.

```py
self.time = [0,1/6,1/3,1/2,1,2,4,6,8,10]
```

[image: Temperature Control]

Here is a complete script with the modifications:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

class Model(GEKKO):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.time = [0,1/6,1/3,1/2,1,2,4,6,8,10]

    R = self.Const(value=2) # Thermal resistance 
    C = self.Const(value=0.5) # Thermal capacity

    self.T0 = self.FV(value=12) # External temperature
    self.T0.FSTATUS = 1

    # Variables
    self.T = self.CV(value=22)
    self.T.STATUS = 1 
    self.options.CV_TYPE = 2
    self.T.SP = 24
    self.T.TR_INIT = 1

    self.q1 = self.MV(value=0) # Heating power
    self.q1.DCOST = 1
    self.q1.STATUS = 1

    self.q3 = self.FV(value=0.5) # Another internal heat source
    self.q3.FSTATUS = 1

    # Equations
    self.Equation(R * C * self.T.dt() + self.T == R * self.q1 + self.T0 + R * self.q3)

    self.options.IMODE = 6 # optimal control mode

  def optimize(self):
    self.solve(disp=False) # solve

T0 = np.random.normal(13, 0.1, 60) # External temeprature varies randomly over time
q3 = np.random.normal(2, 0.01, 60) # Internal heat generation varies randomly over time
q1 = np.zeros(30)
temp = np.zeros(30)
   
m = Model()

for t in range(30):
    print(f'Cycle {t}')
    m.T0.MEAS = T0[t]
    m.q3.MEAS = q3[t]

    m.optimize()
    if (m.options.APPSTATUS==1):
        q1[t] = m.q1.NEWVAL
        temp[t] = m.T.PRED[1]
    else:
        q1[t] = 0    
        temp[t] = 0
        
    #m.q1.MEAS = q1[t]
    #m.T.MEAS = temp[t]
     
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(np.arange(30),q1,'b-',label=r'$q1$')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(np.arange(30),temp,'b-',label=r'$t1$')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

There are additional temperature control examples with the [TCLab modules (A-H)](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/AdvancedTemperatureControl).